# segue to detailed view controller

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, firebase

I have a view controller with a collection view and when I click on the cell of the collection view I want to segue into a controller that has all the post the user of the cell I clicked has.

```
var posts = NSMutableArray()

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
if segue.identifier == "UsersProfile" {
   let vc = segue.destination as! UsersProfileViewController
   let postsForUser = posts.filter {
       guard let post = $0 as? [String : Any] else { 
          return false 
       }  
       return post["username"] as? String == selectedUserName 
   }
   print("postForUser = \(postsForUser)")
   vc.posts = postsForUser as! NSMutableArray
  }
}
```

It was working perfectly fine when I had xcode 8 and when I updated to xcode 9 it crashes when I click the cell and I am not really sure how to identify issues in xcode 9.

Comment: What's the crash, and on what line?

Comment: @Smartcat `vc.posts = postsForUser as! NSMutableArray`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the post dictionary contains value with "username" key which is a String type so the filter will return the array of `Dictionary<String, Any>` or [[String: Any]] not NSMutableArray. Also `NSMutableArray` is Objective-C collection type, not used in Swift. So the posts in ProfileViewController should be of type `[[String: Any]]`

```
let postsForUser: [[String: Any]] = posts.filter {
   guard let post = $0 as? [String : Any] else { 
      return false 
   }  
   return post["username"] as? String == selectedUserName 
}
print("postForUser = \(postsForUser)")
vc.posts = postsForUser //vc.posts should be [[String: Any]]
```

Comment: in the line `vc.posts = postsForUser //vc.posts should be [[String: Any]]` i get the error Cannot assign value of type '[[String : Any]]' to type 'NSMutableArray' Insert ' as! NSMutableArray' but then when I do that it crashes still

Comment: change UsersProfileViewController posts type to [[String: Any]]

Answer (score 0):

postsForUser is of type [Any] (i.e. an Array).  It's not an NSMutableArray.  You're forcing a cast to NSMutableArray else crash, so it must crash.

So think about what type you truly want for postsForUser and be consistent about it.  Also, avoid using as! since it's just asking to crash.  It's only appropriate in a very narrow set of circumstances.

Comment: so I changed postsForUser to NSMutableArray `let postsForUser = posts.filter { guard let post = $0 as? [String : Any] else { return false }; return post["username"] as? String == name } as! NSMutableArray` but now I get an error on this line